# What is purpose of exporting system using tcl scripts generated by Qsys?

Tags: intel-fpga

To "Export" a Qsys system we merely need the .qsys file.

Inside Qsys (now called Platform Designer) we have the option where we can export the system as a .tcl script. The options are the in the file menu and these are:

i. Export System as Platform Designer script (.tcl)

ii. Export System as hw.tcl Component

My questions are:

1. Why do we need these when we can just send off the .qsys file?
2. Why do we have two options and not just one i.e what is the difference between them?
3. Is the Qsys system included when we archive a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCL file is an alternative to the Qsys file. It allows you to use the system as a subsystem in Qsys.

So why would you want it? Because you can edit the file as a general TCL script, allowing you to add more parameter options that can't be done in Qsys graphically.

For example say you want a system with N submodules - that can't be done in Qsys, but it can be done in the TCL file with a for loop.

As another example, say you have a system that can select between different subsystems depending on a parameter. Again you can only do that in the TCL version.

You only need the TCL version if you are going to use it. Otherwise there is no point.

Comment: I noticed that Qsys GUI does not allow us to add generic to the Qsys system top level. Thus, any internal components will not be configurable once the Qsys system has been instantiated in an RTL file. Is there a work around for this too?

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 once HDL is generated, there are a lot of things you can't easily change. You are best not changing the HDL directly, but regenerating the Qsys system to update HDL in the output directory.

Comment: But how to add generics into the > Qsys top level system <

Comment: What do you mean by generics? Things like not/and/or gates? If so, you make a custom Qsys component. We have ones we made for several N-bit gates.

Comment: See generic is a constant that is passed into VHDL entities. I am not sure what they are called in Verilog. Basically we an use them to alter how the component shall synthesize. It seems that we cannot create one of these inside Qsys system top level.

Comment: Ah, same as verilog parameters. I'm not sure you can - at least I've never found a way. The closest you can get are instance parameters and the instance script. But again you have to regenerate the HDL for that to work.

Comment: I have for one system gone as far as creating a quartus pre-flow script that modifies the generated HDL file to set parameter values for instances (such as a compile timestamp core).

Comment: Yes, I got update from Intel. He said (as I suspected) that it is not supported in Qsys. We can modify the RTL my hand to get this if we want but of course the modified code shall be lost once the system is updated. Or we can try your way Tom.